# Casting uint8_t to int8_t

Tags: c, microchip, xc8

Using Microchip XC8 I have a construct

```
int16_t test;
uint8_t msb = 0xff;
uint8_t lsb = 0xf4;
uint8_t hyst = 0xff; 

test = ((((int16_t)msb)<<8) + (int16_t)lsb) + (int8_t)hyst);
```

I would expect test to be -13 (oxFFF3) as i used signed numbers but it is calculated as 0xF3.

Why?

Edit: Tried with gcc and the result is what I expected.

Comment: Standard integer conversions and undefined behaviour.

Comment: This is undefined behavior if `int` is 16 bits due to the left shift. What is `sizeof(int)`?

Comment: Then it's UB. If you change `((int16_t)msb)` into `((uint16_t)msb)`, you will get rid of the undefined behavior, although it will still be implementation-defined.

Comment: the cast to `int16_t` is redundant and just reduces readability because those values will be promoted to int anyway.

Answer (score 1):

As Olaf correctly remarked, the shift operation may have no defined behavior if `int` has a width of 16 since you are shifting a bit into the sign bit of the `int16_t`. Then your code is erroneous and you can't deduce anything about the value that your platform might realized.

If `int` is larger, everything is fine for the expression, you are only adding up positive values that fit into `int`. But the resulting value then will be converted back to `int16_t` due to the initialization, which results in an "implementation defined" conversion or the raise of a signal. So you should check your compiler documentation what your platform does in these cases, and it is probably a good idea to avoid it if you can.

Comment: It's only undefined if `int` is 16 bits, because integer promotion is performed before the shift.

Comment: @interjay, see my edit, in the other case the UB is in the conversion to `int16_t`.

Comment: If int is larger, the conversion to `int16_t` would be implementation defined.

Comment: If overflow there is in the conversion from `int` to `int16_t`, the behavior of that overflow is implementation-defined (it can be an implementation-defined signal, but it isn't one very often on modern architectures, even embedded ones).

Comment: For some reason you like to use a circumlocution like “not having defined behavior” for illegal uses of signed left shift, but it is explicitly named “undefined behavior” in the standard. As someone who insists others use the mot juste (http://www.openwall.com/lists/musl/2015/07/17/2 ), it would be simpler just to call it what it is called in the standard.

Comment: The shift works as expected and (((((int16_t)msb)<<8) + (int16_t)lsb)) evaluates correctly but not with the add of the int8_t at the end.

Comment: @PascalCuoq, I do that for a reason. The primary problem of code is usually that it is erroneous. UB is only a consequence of that, and I think the term is too often mystified. The primary goal of the C standard is to define behavior of code not to serve as excuse for nasal daemons.

Comment: So how should it be done?  A 16-bit value fetched as two bytes from eeprom and a signed char added to that. All being unsigned chars when fetched.

Comment: @Frog, this depends on the semantic that you want your operation to have. The result of the mathematical operation is a value that is larger than `INT16_MAX`. What do you want that to be?

Comment: As I say above  msb<<8 + lsb is a signed 16-bit integer and hyst is a signed char.  But as it looks if I go with an intermediate uint16_t  and then cast the result to int16-t it all works.  I think gcc do a better job of this standard way or not.

Comment: Any reason my comment was deleted?

Comment: @interjay: This is for PIC16 MCUs. So, `int`does have 16 bits.

Answer (score 0):

OK from the comments

```
int16_t test;
uint8_t msb = 0xff;
uint8_t lsb = 0xf4;
uint8_t hyst = 0xff; 

test = (int16_t)(((uint16_t)msb)<<8) + (uint16_t)lsb) + (int8_t)hyst;
```

solves the problem. Thank you guys!

Comment: In general you should not mix signed and unsigned. If you assemble bitfields, using unsigned is often the way to go.